# Check whether internal name of column exists in Sharepoint list

Tags: jquery

I want to check whether the field internal name exists or not and if exists then get its internal name using  $().SPServices

Comment: Could you give more information in witch context you want to do it? In View, in List Form, or in any context using JSOM?

Comment: In any Context using JSOM

Comment: You need to try yourself first. Please edit the post and add the code you've come up with and we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to achieve this using JSOM (not JQuery, actually).

When you try to get field that does not exists in list, you usually will get an exception from SharePoint. So the best way would be to get internal names of all fields, and iterate through them.

Here is pseudo script:

```
var fieldExists = false;
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("List Title");
var fields = list.get_fields();
context.load(fields, "Include(InternalName)");
context.executeQueryAsync(
    function (sender, args) {
        var fieldEnumerator = fields.getEnumerator();
        while (fieldEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var field = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
            var name = field.get_internalName();
            if (name == "FieldInternalName") {
                fieldExists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```